# Unable to decrypt CAST5 Encrypted PGP file using Bouncy Castle libraries on Java 8

Tags: java, encryption, java-8, bouncycastle

We are using Bouncy Castle Java libraries for PGP Decryption and all was working well till we hit the point where we had to decrypt a file with the following attributes (snippet from `pgpdump <filename>` output)

```sh
> pgpdump file-name.csv.pgp                                                                                                          
New: Symmetric-Key Encrypted Session Key Packet(tag 3)(29 bytes)
    New version(4)
    Sym alg - CAST5(sym 3)
    Salted string-to-key(s2k 1):
        Hash alg - SHA1(hash 2)
        Salt - c3 89 7b 22 c0 90 a2 1f 
    Encrypted session key
        -> sym alg(1 bytes) + session key
New: Public-Key Encrypted Session Key Packet(tag 1)(268 bytes)
    New version(3)
    Key ID - 0x00FB426B9D39D2D9
    Pub alg - RSA Encrypt or Sign(pub 1)
    RSA m^e mod n(2048 bits) - ...
        -> m = sym alg(1 byte) + checksum(2 bytes) + PKCS-1 block type 02
New: Public-Key Encrypted Session Key Packet(tag 1)(268 bytes)
    New version(3)
    Key ID - 0x13BCC3DF42A3585C
    Pub alg - RSA Encrypt or Sign(pub 1)
    RSA m^e mod n(2048 bits) - ...
        -> m = sym alg(1 byte) + checksum(2 bytes) + PKCS-1 block type 02
New: Symmetrically Encrypted and MDC Packet(tag 18)(8192 bytes) partial start
    Ver 1
    Encrypted data [sym alg is specified in pub-key encrypted session key]
        (plain text + MDC SHA1(20 bytes))
```

I am able to decrypt the file on my mac using

```sh
gpg --passphrase <passphrase> -v -d --pinentry-mode=loopback -o foo.out
```

Using the java code below [based on BouncyCastle example](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=NoYouShutup/CryptMeme/CryptMeme-master/CryptMeme/src/java/org/bouncycastle/openpgp/examples/ByteArrayHandler.java), I am ending up with `org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException: Exception creating cipher CAST5`.

```java
public static byte[] decrypt(
        byte[] encrypted,
        char[] passPhrase)
        throws IOException, PGPException, NoSuchProviderException
    {
        InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(encrypted);

        in = PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(in);

        PGPObjectFactory         pgpF = new PGPObjectFactory(in);
        PGPEncryptedDataList     enc;
        Object                          o = pgpF.nextObject();

        //
        // the first object might be a PGP marker packet.
        //
        if (o instanceof PGPEncryptedDataList)
        {
            enc = (PGPEncryptedDataList)o;
        }
        else
        {
            enc = (PGPEncryptedDataList)pgpF.nextObject();
        }

        PGPPBEEncryptedData pbe = (PGPPBEEncryptedData)enc.get(0);

        //****************************************
        // Hitting an exception here while doing pbe.getDataStream()... 
        // Getting  "org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException: Exception creating cipher CAST5"
        //****************************************
        InputStream clear = pbe.getDataStream(new JcePBEDataDecryptorFactoryBuilder(new JcaPGPDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder().setProvider("BC").build()).setProvider("BC").build(passPhrase)); 

        PGPObjectFactory        pgpFact = new PGPObjectFactory(clear);

        PGPCompressedData   cData = (PGPCompressedData)pgpFact.nextObject();

        pgpFact = new PGPObjectFactory(cData.getDataStream());

        PGPLiteralData ld = (PGPLiteralData)pgpFact.nextObject();

        return Streams.readAll(ld.getInputStream());
    }
```

Exception info -

```
org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException: Exception creating cipher
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.OperatorHelper.createDataDecryptor(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.operator.jcajce.JcePBEDataDecryptorFactoryBuilder$1.createDataDecryptor(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPPBEEncryptedData.getDataStream(Unknown Source)

...
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown symmetric algorithm: 112
    at org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPUtil.getSymmetricCipherName(Unknown Source)
    ... 21 more
```

I tried running `Security.getAlgorithms("Cipher")` [as suggested here](https://dev-crypto.bouncycastle.narkive.com/Y3qlYiKN/problem-with-example-bytearrayhandler-java#post3) and I do not see CAST5 in the list of returned algorithms.

I'm on Java 1.8 and using Bouncy Castle libraries below

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.62</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcpg-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.62</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Any ideas what should I be pursuing next?
I also made sure that my code is setting `Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());` during startup.

I am feeling this should be a matter of adding more support to JVM Ciper Suites. But I don't know where to start.

Please advice.

---

**NOTE:** The above code was an example from internet, but based on Maarten Bodewes comments, I realized after copying that code from internet locally - I had made a lot of changes to get it functional.

### Exact code I am using from my machine

```java
public static void decryptSymmetricFile(
            InputStream in,
            char[] passwd,
            String outFileName) throws IOException {

        in = PGPUtil.getDecoderStream(in);

        PGPObjectFactory pgpF = new JcaPGPObjectFactory(in);
        PGPEncryptedDataList enc;

        Object o = pgpF.nextObject();
        if (o instanceof PGPEncryptedDataList) {
            enc = (PGPEncryptedDataList) o;
        } else {
            enc = (PGPEncryptedDataList) pgpF.nextObject();
        }

        Iterator<?> it = enc.getEncryptedDataObjects();
        PGPPBEEncryptedData      pbe = (PGPPBEEncryptedData) it.next();

        try {
            Security.getAlgorithms("Cipher");

        //****************************************
        // Hitting an exception here while doing pbe.getDataStream()... 
        // Getting  "org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPException: Exception creating cipher CAST5"
        //****************************************
            InputStream dataStream = pbe.getDataStream((new JcePBEDataDecryptorFactoryBuilder((new JcaPGPDigestCalculatorProviderBuilder()).setProvider("BC").build())).setProvider("BC").build(passwd));
            JcaPGPObjectFactory pgpObjectFactory = new JcaPGPObjectFactory(dataStream);
            PGPCompressedData pgpCompressedData = (PGPCompressedData) pgpObjectFactory.nextObject();
            pgpObjectFactory = new JcaPGPObjectFactory(pgpCompressedData.getDataStream());
            PGPLiteralData literalData = (PGPLiteralData) pgpObjectFactory.nextObject();

            ByteArrayOutputStream    bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            InputStream              unc = literalData.getInputStream();
            int                      ch;

            while ((ch = unc.read()) >= 0)
            {
                bOut.write(ch);
            }

            if (pbe.isIntegrityProtected() && !pbe.verify())
            {
                throw new PGPException("Data is integrity protected but integrity is lost.");
            }

            OutputStream fOut = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outFileName));
            Streams.pipeAll(new ByteArrayInputStream(bOut.toByteArray()), fOut);
            fOut.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            logger.error(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: How old is your BC library? Because some initial checks I see that you are using an API that was discontinued after v1.50 and deprecated probably long before that. And I do see CAST5 (and CAST6) in my Cipher output after registering BC. So I'm a bit stunned to the point that I don't completely believe above post.

Comment: I am glad you were able to find some anomaly. As posted above, i am using BC version 1.62 libraries... per pom.xml and maven packaging.. can you pls suggest the link to the new api documentation you are referring to ..or some examples.. I am new to crypto world and googling for documentation only yeilded me https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=NoYouShutup/CryptMeme/CryptMeme-master/CryptMeme/src/java/org/bouncycastle/openpgp/examples/ByteArrayHandler.java

Comment: I'm not referring to any specific example, I just tried compiling your code, which failed due to `PGPObjectFactory` taking two parameters instead of one, and then finding the change of code in GitHub. So I don't see how above code compiles with 1.62. Do you maybe have another BC PG lib included somewhere?

Comment: Maarten - Apologize for the confusion, after copying that code to my local - I made a whole bunch of changes, did not realize it during my post. I jus updated the above post with the exact code I have issues with. Apologies again.

Comment: That's still a bit weird code, you don't print anything when doing `getCiphers`. What happens if you do `  Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
  Set<String> ciphers = Security.getAlgorithms("Cipher");
  if (ciphers.contains("CAST5")) {
   System.out.println("Found CAST5");
  }
`?

Comment: I was debugging / stepping through code and validating the values. Here is a debugging screenshot of the above suggestion. I am seeing "Found CAST5" printed in the console, but the exception stack trace is the same. - https://photos.app.goo.gl/dCM7eSgrjf6qiqqj9

Comment: Ajajajay. I guess this is the point where you enter a bug report or start stepping through the code yourself (and compare with a PGP message encrypted using AES).

Comment: Note that you should be able to use exactly the same version of the source code to step through the BC classes (without having to build them, I mean) from your fave IDE.

Comment: If you use the code that prints _Found CAST5_ in the console, does the stack trace still contain _Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown symmetric algorithm: 112_? This part is missing in the screenshot.

Comment: Yes, it so shows - "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: unknown symmetric algorithm: 112" when scrolling down the stack trace